# Truncate levels of dataframe - tidyverse (stringr, haven)

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I have a dataframe containing questionnaire data from an online survey platform. I'm trying to write parts of this dataframe into a SPSS file with tidyverse's `haven::write_sav()`, but I have some data wrangling problems, which are messing around with the data.

The thing is, that SPSS only allows variable levels, which are shorter than 120 characters. I have variable levels which exceed this limit, which doesn't allow me to write a `*.sav` file with the dataframe.

So my idea was to truncate every occuring level of every dataframe column to <= 120 characters, to make sure the writing process is not interrupted, but I can't figure out how to manipulate all levels from all columns.

I'm extracting the levels like this:

```
df %>%
    lapply(levels)
```

But afterwards I'm just lost how to deal with the list I'm getting in return, especially since most elements of this list simply don't have any levels (and are assigned NULL using lapply).

I've tried something like this, but afterwards `haven::write_sav()` only writes "1" instead of the actual value per variable into the SPSS spreadsheet:

```
df <- df %>%
          as.matrix()    %>%
          str_trunc(120) %>%
          as.data.frame()

haven::write_sav(df, "test.sav")
```

I'm looking for a tidyverse solution of this problelm, if possible and any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: perhaps `df %>% mutate_all(strtrim, width = n)` where `n <- 120`. Regarding the issue of writing `1`, may be its because of `factor` columns.  Try with `%>% as.data.frame(., stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Works like a charm! Additionally this way also seems to eliminate the issue of just writing `1` to the output file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `strtrim` (`base R`) applied on all the columns (`mutate_all`)

```
library(dplyr)
n <- 120
df %>%
   mutate_all(strtrim, width = n)
```

---

In the OP's original code, `as.data.frame` converts it to a `data.frame` with `character` columns by default (`stringsAsFactors = TRUE`) are `factor`s unless it is specified with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`